# ToggleButtons changes reference's value

Tags: flutter, dart, toggle

I'm new to Dart/Flutter and object oriented programming in general so I apologize if this is basic.

I'd like to restore the initial values for a toggle button if the user pushes the back button instead of saving. I'm trying to create a copy of the initial values to restore but the toggle button is changing my restore values.  My elevated button (below) seems to behave as expected.

Can anyone explain this? Is the button changing the value while the toggle is changing the reference? Any solutions besides building a custom toggle out of buttons?

```
List<bool> initValues = [true,false,false];
List<bool> isSelected = initValues;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
  ),);}}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {

 @override
   _MyWidget createState() => _MyWidget();}

class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return 
  Column(
  children:
[
 ToggleButtons(
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.not_interested),
    Text('P'),
    Text('S'),
  ],
  onPressed: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      for (int buttonIndex = 0;
          buttonIndex < isSelected.length;
          buttonIndex++) {
        if (buttonIndex == index) {
          isSelected[buttonIndex] = true;
        } else {
          isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
        }
      }
    }
 );
  },
  isSelected: isSelected,
),
 ElevatedButton(
   child: Text('P'),
   onPressed: (){
    
     isSelected = [false,true,false];


   }),
  ElevatedButton(
   child: Text('Print Value'),
   onPressed: (){
     
     print(initValues);
     print(isSelected);
          }),
   ]
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

add WillPopScope widget as the following:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(onWillPop:() async {
  //reset your toggle button here
  return true;
},child:
    Scaffold(body:YourBody()));}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I plan to use onWillPop however the variable I try to use to reset the toggle button seems to change with the toggle. In my example code both 'initValues' and 'isSelected' variables change to the Toggle state however the button elevated button does not change both.